# Running Sqoop with Oozie Error: Can not create a Path from an empty string

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I am trying to Run Sqoop export with Oozie. I can run simple Sqoop commands (list-tables etc) and I can run my Sqoop export command from the cmd line, however when I run with Oozie I get the following error in my Yarn logs:

Error:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/41235/mapreduce.tar.gz/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/41709/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Note: /tmp/sqoop-yarn/compile/ff5ff27843de6fb697dddfb18c85dbbb/tmp_fact_kpi_da20.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.uploadFiles(JobResourceUploader.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ExportJobBase.java:326)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runJob(ExportJobBase.java:303)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java:444)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager.exportTable(SQLServerManager.java:192)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:81)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:100)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:225)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:197)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:179)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:58)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
```

My workflow.xml is:

```
<workflow-app name="${jobName}" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    <start to="sqoop-export" />
    <action name="sqoop-export">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.action.sharelib.for.sqoop</name> 
                    <value>sqoop,hive,hcatalog</value> 
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.sqoop.log.level</name> 
                    <value>${debugLevel}</value> 
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name> 
                    <value>1</value> 
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name> 
                    <value>thrift://****:9083</value> 
                </property>
                <property>
                  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
                  <value>/apps/hive/warehouse</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <command>export --hcatalog-database modeling_reporting --hcatalog-table fact_kpi_da20 --table tmp_fact_kpi_da20 --connect jdbc:sqlserver://****.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=****;user=****;password=****
            </command>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="sqoop-load-fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="sqoop-load-fail">
        <message>Sqoop export failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

And my job.properties includes:

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=/user/abc
```

I run the job with:

```
oozie job -config job.properties -run
```

Additional logs show the job is able to connect to my destination table and verifies that my columns match:

```
7222 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager  - Finished writing jar file /tmp/sqoop-yarn/compile/24e897ef3439fabb89090a4dbe4c9be1/tmp_fact_kpi_da20.jar
7222 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager  - Finished writing jar file /tmp/sqoop-yarn/compile/24e897ef3439fabb89090a4dbe4c9be1/tmp_fact_kpi_da20.jar
7235 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase  - Beginning export of tmp_fact_kpi_da20
7235 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase  - Beginning export of tmp_fact_kpi_da20
7235 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation  - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
7240 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation  - mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
7240 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation  - mapred.map.max.attempts is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.maxattempts
7240 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase  - Configuring HCatalog for export job
7240 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase  - Configuring HCatalog for export job
7257 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Configuring HCatalog specific details for job
7257 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Configuring HCatalog specific details for job
7493 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM [tmp_fact_kpi_da20] AS t WHERE 1=0
7493 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM [tmp_fact_kpi_da20] AS t WHERE 1=0
7493 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Using fetchSize for next query: 1000
7493 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Using fetchSize for next query: 1000
7493 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [tmp_fact_kpi_da20] AS t WHERE 1=0
7493 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [tmp_fact_kpi_da20] AS t WHERE 1=0
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column eventdate of type [-9, 10, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column eventdate of type [-9, 10, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column clientregion of type [-9, 4, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column clientregion of type [-9, 4, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column clientjourney of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column clientjourney of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column eventtype of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column eventtype of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column eventreason of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column eventreason of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column feature of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column feature of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column customerdevice of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column customerdevice of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column customerbrowser of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column customerbrowser of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column customercountryiso2 of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column customercountryiso2 of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column clientcurrencyiso3 of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column clientcurrencyiso3 of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column eventcount of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column eventcount of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column uniqueeventcount of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column uniqueeventcount of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column sales of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column sales of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column salesvalue of type [3, 38, 2]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column salesvalue of type [3, 38, 2]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column salesvaluegbp of type [3, 38, 2]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column salesvaluegbp of type [3, 38, 2]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column started_customersurveys of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column started_customersurveys of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column completed_customersurveys of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column completed_customersurveys of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column started_emailsubscriptions of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column started_emailsubscriptions of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column completed_emailsubscriptions of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column completed_emailsubscriptions of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column started_problemsolversurveys of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column started_problemsolversurveys of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column completed_problemsolversurveys of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column completed_problemsolversurveys of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column scenario of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column scenario of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column abtestgroup of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column abtestgroup of type [-9, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column abtestid of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column abtestid of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column abtestiscontrol of type [-7, 1, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column abtestiscontrol of type [-7, 1, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column appversion of type [12, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column appversion of type [12, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column agentid of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column agentid of type [-5, 19, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column pdate of type [12, 50, 0]
7582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Found column pdate of type [12, 50, 0]
7670 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Database column names projected : [eventdate, clientregion, clientjourney, eventtype, eventreason, feature, customerdevice, customerbrowser, customercountryiso2, clientcurrencyiso3, eventcount, uniqueeventcount, sales, salesvalue, salesvaluegbp, started_customersurveys, completed_customersurveys, started_emailsubscriptions, completed_emailsubscriptions, started_problemsolversurveys, completed_problemsolversurveys, scenario, abtestgroup, abtestid, abtestiscontrol, appversion, agentid, pdate]
7670 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Database column names projected : [eventdate, clientregion, clientjourney, eventtype, eventreason, feature, customerdevice, customerbrowser, customercountryiso2, clientcurrencyiso3, eventcount, uniqueeventcount, sales, salesvalue, salesvaluegbp, started_customersurveys, completed_customersurveys, started_emailsubscriptions, completed_emailsubscriptions, started_problemsolversurveys, completed_problemsolversurveys, scenario, abtestgroup, abtestid, abtestiscontrol, appversion, agentid, pdate]
7670 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Database column name - info map :
    started_customersurveys : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    pdate : [Type : 12,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    uniqueeventcount : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    sales : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    customerbrowser : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    salesvalue : [Type : 3,Precision : 38,Scale : 2]
    abtestiscontrol : [Type : -7,Precision : 1,Scale : 0]
    feature : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    scenario : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    clientregion : [Type : -9,Precision : 4,Scale : 0]
    eventcount : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    customercountryiso2 : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    completed_emailsubscriptions : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    salesvaluegbp : [Type : 3,Precision : 38,Scale : 2]
    abtestid : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    agentid : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    started_emailsubscriptions : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    completed_problemsolversurveys : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    appversion : [Type : 12,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    customerdevice : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    clientjourney : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    eventdate : [Type : -9,Precision : 10,Scale : 0]
    eventreason : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    abtestgroup : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    clientcurrencyiso3 : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    completed_customersurveys : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    started_problemsolversurveys : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    eventtype : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]

7670 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Database column name - info map :
    started_customersurveys : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    pdate : [Type : 12,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    uniqueeventcount : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    sales : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    customerbrowser : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    salesvalue : [Type : 3,Precision : 38,Scale : 2]
    abtestiscontrol : [Type : -7,Precision : 1,Scale : 0]
    feature : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    scenario : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    clientregion : [Type : -9,Precision : 4,Scale : 0]
    eventcount : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    customercountryiso2 : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    completed_emailsubscriptions : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    salesvaluegbp : [Type : 3,Precision : 38,Scale : 2]
    abtestid : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    agentid : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    started_emailsubscriptions : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    completed_problemsolversurveys : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    appversion : [Type : 12,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    customerdevice : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    clientjourney : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    eventdate : [Type : -9,Precision : 10,Scale : 0]
    eventreason : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    abtestgroup : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    clientcurrencyiso3 : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]
    completed_customersurveys : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    started_problemsolversurveys : [Type : -5,Precision : 19,Scale : 0]
    eventtype : [Type : -9,Precision : 50,Scale : 0]

7834 [main] INFO  org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache  - Initializing cache: eviction-timeout=120 initial-capacity=50 maximum-capacity=50
7872 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://d-u2-prcs-sv-01.veproduction.dom:9083
7917 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Connected to metastore.
10113 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - HCatalog full table schema fields = [eventdate, clientregion, clientjourney, eventtype, eventreason, feature, customerdevice, customerbrowser, customercountryiso2, clientcurrencyiso3, eventcount, uniqueeventcount, sales, salesvalue, salesvaluegbp, started_customersurveys, completed_customersurveys, started_emailsubscriptions, completed_emailsubscriptions, started_problemsolversurveys, completed_problemsolversurveys, scenario, abtestgroup, abtestid, abtestiscontrol, appversion, agentid, pdate]
10113 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - HCatalog full table schema fields = [eventdate, clientregion, clientjourney, eventtype, eventreason, feature, customerdevice, customerbrowser, customercountryiso2, clientcurrencyiso3, eventcount, uniqueeventcount, sales, salesvalue, salesvaluegbp, started_customersurveys, completed_customersurveys, started_emailsubscriptions, completed_emailsubscriptions, started_problemsolversurveys, completed_problemsolversurveys, scenario, abtestgroup, abtestid, abtestiscontrol, appversion, agentid, pdate]
10849 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - HCatalog table partitioning key fields = [pdate]
10849 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - HCatalog table partitioning key fields = [pdate]
10849 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - HCatalog projected schema fields = [eventdate, clientregion, clientjourney, eventtype, eventreason, feature, customerdevice, customerbrowser, customercountryiso2, clientcurrencyiso3, eventcount, uniqueeventcount, sales, salesvalue, salesvaluegbp, started_customersurveys, completed_customersurveys, started_emailsubscriptions, completed_emailsubscriptions, started_problemsolversurveys, completed_problemsolversurveys, scenario, abtestgroup, abtestid, abtestiscontrol, appversion, agentid, pdate]
10849 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - HCatalog projected schema fields = [eventdate, clientregion, clientjourney, eventtype, eventreason, feature, customerdevice, customerbrowser, customercountryiso2, clientcurrencyiso3, eventcount, uniqueeventcount, sales, salesvalue, salesvaluegbp, started_customersurveys, completed_customersurveys, started_emailsubscriptions, completed_emailsubscriptions, started_problemsolversurveys, completed_problemsolversurveys, scenario, abtestgroup, abtestid, abtestiscontrol, appversion, agentid, pdate]
10889 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - HCatalog job : Hive Home = /usr/lib/hive
10889 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - HCatalog job : Hive Home = /usr/lib/hive
10889 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - HCatalog job:  HCatalog Home = /usr/lib/hcatalog
10889 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - HCatalog job:  HCatalog Home = /usr/lib/hcatalog
10920 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Adding jar files under /usr/lib/hcatalog/share/hcatalog to distributed cache
10920 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Adding jar files under /usr/lib/hcatalog/share/hcatalog to distributed cache
10920 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - No files under /usr/lib/hcatalog/share/hcatalog to add to distributed cache for hcatalog job
10920 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - No files under /usr/lib/hcatalog/share/hcatalog to add to distributed cache for hcatalog job
10920 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Adding jar files under /usr/lib/hcatalog/lib to distributed cache
10920 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Adding jar files under /usr/lib/hcatalog/lib to distributed cache
10920 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - No files under /usr/lib/hcatalog/lib to add to distributed cache for hcatalog job
10920 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - No files under /usr/lib/hcatalog/lib to add to distributed cache for hcatalog job
10920 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Adding jar files under /usr/lib/hive/lib to distributed cache
10920 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Adding jar files under /usr/lib/hive/lib to distributed cache
10920 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - No files under /usr/lib/hive/lib to add to distributed cache for hcatalog job
10920 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - No files under /usr/lib/hive/lib to add to distributed cache for hcatalog job
10920 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Adding jar files under /usr/lib/hcatalog/share/hcatalog/storage-handlers to distributed cache (recursively)
10920 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Adding jar files under /usr/lib/hcatalog/share/hcatalog/storage-handlers to distributed cache (recursively)
10920 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - No files under /usr/lib/hcatalog/share/hcatalog/storage-handlers to add to distributed cache for hcatalog job
10920 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - No files under /usr/lib/hcatalog/share/hcatalog/storage-handlers to add to distributed cache for hcatalog job
10921 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - Using InputFormat: class org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatExportFormat
10921 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - Using InputFormat: class org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatExportFormat
10921 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Configuring HCatalog for export job
10921 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Configuring HCatalog for export job
10921 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Ignoring configuration request for HCatalog info
10921 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities  - Ignoring configuration request for HCatalog info
11112 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation  - mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative
11112 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation  - mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
11112 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation  - mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
11113 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - Adding to job classpath: file:/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/14417/sqoop-1.4.6.2.6.2.0-205.jar
11113 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - Adding to job classpath: file:/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/14417/sqoop-1.4.6.2.6.2.0-205.jar
11114 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - Adding to job classpath: file:/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/louiscronin/filecache/1096/mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar
11114 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - Adding to job classpath: file:/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/louiscronin/filecache/1096/mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar
11115 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - Adding to job classpath: file:/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/14417/sqoop-1.4.6.2.6.2.0-205.jar
11115 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - Adding to job classpath: file:/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/14417/sqoop-1.4.6.2.6.2.0-205.jar
11116 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - Adding to job classpath: file:/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/14417/sqoop-1.4.6.2.6.2.0-205.jar
11116 [main] DEBUG org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - Adding to job classpath: file:/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/14417/sqoop-1.4.6.2.6.2.0-205.jar
11116 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - SQOOP_HOME is unset. May not be able to find all job dependencies.
11116 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - SQOOP_HOME is unset. May not be able to find all job dependencies.
11210 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.AHSProxy  - Connecting to Application History server at d-u2-prcs-nm-03.veproduction.dom/172.28.50.22:10200
11330 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider  - Looking for the active RM in [rm1, rm2]...
11336 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider  - Found active RM [rm2]
11518 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - Cleaning up the staging area /user/louiscronin/.staging/job_1612961662367_2162
11546 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureFileSystemThreadPoolExecutor  - Disabling threads for Delete operation as thread count 0 is <= 1
11554 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureFileSystemThreadPoolExecutor  - Time taken for Delete operation is: 9 ms with threads: 0
11603 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop  - Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
11603 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop  - Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
```

Comment: Sqoop Export writes to an intermediate directory. Use --export-dir . Check this link for reference. https://timepasstechies.com/oozie-workflow-example-sqoop-action-end-end-configuration/